# How to prevent my app update notification to user when I update to play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I want that when I update my app to playstore, the older user who already installed my app, prevent to get any kind of update notification of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this.. Update notification is managed by the **google play store** and you can not control over there to restrict any particular update notification of your application.
Still you want any custom check to get any updates you can do in two ways:

**One is:** [`Link-1`](https://github.com/rampo/UpdateChecker) which can be integrate your application code to get manually update and alert.

**Second is:** the market notifications are not something exposed to app developers in any way. If you want to notify your users you'll need to build that into your app: set up a server that exposes an HTTP url that reports the latest version, then use an AlarmManager to call that URL and see if the version on the device is the same as the latest version. If it isn't pop up a message or notification and send them to the market to upgrade.

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: actually i want 2 prevent user to update notification cause my app run in background and user not know about my app if some 1 install it to some 1 devices thats y

Comment: Your concern is fine but unfortunately you can't prevent it as it is handled by google play store server itself so for better user experience.. :-)

Comment: @RushabhPatel can u tell how to use an HTTP url to check for the update?

The problem I am having is asked here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795783/getting-app-update-notification-without-playstore-app-installed-in-device